DaVinci Resolve 19.0b1 will not start on Ubuntu 24.04
After installing DaVinci Resolve 19.0b1 on Ubuntu 24.04, nothing happens when you try to run the desktop app.
Attempting to run the application in a terminal gives the following error message and then crashes:
> /opt/resolve/bin/resolve
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_once_init_leave_pointer

How can I get DaVinci Resolve to start?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y87MFmcy3lc
Files needed to install DaVinci_Resolve_19
#1 INSTALL DAVINCI RESOLVE
cd ~/Downloads
SKIP_PACKAGE_CHECK=1 ./DaVinci_Resolve_19.0.1_Linux.run

#2 DOWNLOAD PACKAGES
wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pango1.0/libpango-1.0-0_1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pango1.0/libpangoft2-1.0-0_1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pango1.0/libpangocairo-1.0-0_1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0_2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb

#3 EXTRACT
cd ~/Downloads
mkdir /home/hc/libpango
dpkg-deb -x libpangocairo-1.0-0_1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb /home/hc/libpango
dpkg-deb -x libpango-1.0-0_1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb /home/hc/libpango
dpkg-deb -x libpangoft2-1.0-0_1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb /home/hc/libpango
dpkg-deb -x libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0_2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb /home/hc/libpango

#4 COPY
cp /home/hc/libpango/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib* /opt/resolve/libs


I logged in just to say thank you - this was the trick!

Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for so long and this was the trick.

I needed to install these packages before running the installer:
libapr1 libaprutil1 libasound2 libglib2.0-0 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0
After that Resolve gets installed into /opt.
I guess the GNOME stuff included with Resolve is too old, so I replaced a bunch of them with the newer ones already on my system by overwriting the ones in the /opt/resolve/libs directory.
You can do this same with this:
for lib in \
  libglib-2.0.so.0 \
  libgobject-2.0.so.0 \
  libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 \
  libgstsdp-1.0.so.0 \
  libgstwebrtc-1.0.so.0 \
  libgio-2.0.so.0 \
  libgmodule-2.0.so.0 \
  libgstrtp-1.0.so.0 \
  libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 \
  libgstbase-1.0.so.0 \
  libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 \
  libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 \
  libgsttag-1.0.so.0 \
  liborc-0.4.so.0; \
do
    ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/$lib /opt/resolve/libs/
done

I am on a Desktop Computer with an Nvidia RTX4070TI GPU and an Intel i7 CPU.

How exactly did you install those versions? I tried, but the system already has newer versions for most, while libasound2 does not exist with that name ("E: Package 'libasound2' has no installation candidate"). I installed the rest and libasound2* (there are some -data etc. libraries). I still get the same DaVinci installer error. Thanks.

The error message I get when on a fresh 24.04 VM includes this piece of advice:
Package libasound2 is a virtual package provided by:
liboss4-salsa-asound2...
libasound2t64... . I picked libasound2t64

@DanielAdelodun: Did you manage to start the DaVinci Resolve on Ubuntu 24?

@AdeelRazaAzeemi Yeah. Edited, managed to add an OpenFX plugin (gyroflow), and exported the video too.
Haven’t tested everything, but so far no issues.
This was with 19.0b1, I haven’t tried any updated versions.

@DanielAdelodun I finally managed to start the DaVinci Resolve but could not do anything in it, I had Ubuntu 24 with a dedicated GPU, After a lot search I found out that Ubuntu had a graphics driver in kernel; that means you can't install the driver; btw My laptop had Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics Family card and intel does not provide driver for ubuntu. I should also mention n that on Windows (I had dual boot) DaVinci Resolve works perfectly

What do you mean by you could not do anything? As in it froze, or it did not let export the video?
I’m not sure what you mean by ‘graphics driver in kernel’, and you can absolutely install graphics drivers in Linux and Ubuntu…But I should have mentioned the hardware I was using. I’ll edit the original answer.

I was also missing this one libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0

This works!, Ubuntu 24.04.1,  AMD 6700 XT on Ryzen9 3900 XT

Had the same problem with missing packages libapr1, libaprutil1, and libasound2. Installing the first two, and for the third one installing libasound2t64 didn't fix it for me.
For me, these were the steps:

Open Terminal in the extracted folder and run
chmod +x DaVinci_Resolve_19.0b3_Linux.run (or whatever the file name is)

Run ./DaVinci_Resolve_19.0b3_Linux.run --appimage-extract

cd into squashfs-root and run sudo ./AppRun -i. Then it will show you what packages are missing (in my case the 3: ibapr1, libaprutil1, and libasound2).

In the file manager, navigate into the squashfs-root folder and open AppRun with a text editor

Search for, and delete the lines:
libasound2-0.0.0
libapr1-0.0.0
libaprutil1-0.0.0
under function check_ubuntu_package_deps() (so we are modifying the ubuntu required packages, not the SUSE ones). If there are more packages missing, try first installing them with sudo apt install. If still that error comes, delete them from the list in AppRun too (?)

Now in the terminal run sudo ./AppRun -i again. Now it should ask you to process with y.

When the install process is done, you need to replace the libs as already suggested by Daniel's answer. Create a fix-resolve.sh file with this content (copied from https://github.com/odooerpdevelopers/davinci-resolve/tree/main/davinci-19-ubuntu-24):
 ```
 #!/bin/bash

 # Array con los nombres de las bibliotecas
 libraries=(
   "libglib-2.0.so.0"
   "libgobject-2.0.so.0"
   "libgstreamer-1.0.so.0"
   "libgstsdp-1.0.so.0"
   "libgstwebrtc-1.0.so.0"
   "libgio-2.0.so.0"
   "libgmodule-2.0.so.0"
   "libgstrtp-1.0.so.0"
   "libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0"
   "libgstbase-1.0.so.0"
   "libgstvideo-1.0.so.0"
   "libgstaudio-1.0.so.0"
   "libgsttag-1.0.so.0"
   "liborc-0.4.so.0"
 )

 # Loop para crear los enlaces simbólicos
 for lib in "${libraries[@]}"; do
     ln -sf "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/$lib" /opt/resolve/libs/
 done
 ```

 make it executable    
  `sudo chmod +x fix-resolve.sh`    
  and run it    
  `sudo ./fix-resolve.sh`.


Now Resolve should start. I then got "Unsupported GPU processing mode". My Nvidia driver was on version 535, but as the DaVinci pdf says it needs 550. So install with with
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 and then reboot.

Now it worked for me!


Don't forget to backup your system before doing things like installing the nvidia driver. But in my case it all went fine!

To simplify steps 4-6: Once you're sure you've gotten all the packages, you can 'Use SKIP_PACKAGE_CHECK=1 to bypass the system package check'. Line 341 in squashfs-root/AppRun.
Installing was a pain. Odd that AppImages are just broken on Ubuntu right now. Decided to only ask myself "after installing".
